# git: how to add one file as a version of another?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a bash script that I've written during the course of the last week. Today, I've decided to finally give git a try before making any further changes, created a git repository, etc.
The script has two versions: `script.sh` and `script1.sh`. *My question is whether there is a way to tell git that the latter is an updated version of the former?* I've read the beginner chapters of the "git book" about 3 or 4 times now and I'm a little shaky on terminology, still. I don't think that `merge` is what I'm looking for. I've committed both of the files, but from what I understand that just means that they are two separate files of a project to be tracked. From now on I'll just be editing one file with its changes tracked, but is there a way to neatly preserve my work in the version control system from the "pre-git" days? Or am I imagining a function that isn't there?

Comment: A side note: it is very un-Unix to give executable files extensions. If you call your script from another script, and then re-write it in another language, would you change the extension. If so then you have to change all scripts that call the script. (you should instead use #! )

Comment: @richard That's an interesting point to keep in mind! Funnily enough, I do it so that automatic syntax highlighting in VIM would be...Well, automatic haha! I guess I should have my priorities sorted.

Comment: I thing there may be a way to configure vim to look at the `#!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you overwrite `script.sh` with `script1.sh`, after an initial commit. Starting from scratch:

```
git init
git add script.sh
git commit -m "First version of script.sh"
mv script1.sh script.sh
git add script.sh
git commit -m "Second version of script.sh"
```

You'll then be able to see both versions of `script.sh` in `git log`, check out the previous version etc.

Comment: Ha! That's killer! Thank you! So, just to clarify, there isn't a "built-in way", for lack of a better phrase, to do it in git? It simply keeps track of single files? Sorry for being clingy-just trying to wrap my head around the concepts once and for all.

Comment: Yes, it tracks changes to files (single or multiple). It completely replaces the kind of manual version control you're doing with copies of files.

Comment: Yes git does not track renames, some revision control systems do. However this is not a rename. you have script-revision0, script-revision1 etc. Then you put it in to git, and you have script at revision 0 and script at revision 1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

To understand Git you need to think in snapshots which are the commits.
After having changed the file across several commits you could track the changes via `git diff script.sh`

Comment: Yeah, absolutely! I got that part right, I just thought that *maybe* there is a function that lets me track one file as a version of another as opposed to tracking(taking snapshots of) changes in a single file, if that makes sense. Looks like I was wrong. My goal **was** to get the `diff`s between those two files.

Comment: To get the `diff` between the two files, as separate files, you'd just use `diff script.sh script1.sh`. The whole point of `git` is to avoid having to copy files around to be able to compare changes; whenever you have a change that makes sense to keep as an identifiable change, you commit it, and then you can view the history of files as a succession of changes (and see what changed at each step).